# is there any way to use reusable component with same button should perform different functionality

Tags: reactjs

I want to make one reusable component name: ABC 5 times in which all ABC component should have different data and i want to add a functionality where 1st and 5th ABC should have true state by default and the remaining 3 should have false and then i want to close and open particular component with an arrow but the problem is that all component are opening and closing instead of the particular one

Comment: You have to sent the state property to the component from parent, so you specify manualy first and last component as you want as false. Inside the component you set state to that value from property.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

because you should add functionality as a prop from the parent of the component you are using it in. as in

```
const CustomButton = ({handleClick, buttonText, otherProps}) => {

return <button onClick={handleClick}>{buttonText}</button>
}


const App = () => {
return (
  <div>
    <CustomButton buttonText={"SEND"} handleClick={() => {/*fetch something or do something*/}} />
    <CustomButton buttonText={"DELETE"} handleClick={() => {/*do another thing*/}} />
    <CustomButton buttonText={"DO SOMETHING"} handleClick={() => {/*say hi to your users*/}} />
    <CustomButton buttonText={"DO SOMETHING ELSE"} handleClick={() => {/*you can do anything*/}} />
  </div>
)

}
```

if you need to render buttons according to the data count(example: length of an array) you can use Array.map method to render components and use its index to open and close the elements by passing the index as a prop to CustomButton and using the handleClick function as `() => {handleClick(index)}` and handle the operation in just one function in the parent component.

Comment: ok i will try to implement this